# Add TimePicker to Already existing JqueryDatepicker

Tags: jquery, css

I have jquery datepicker. I want to add timepicker to my existing jquery datepicker

Comment: Hi, can you input what you have done so far? this will  help the community to understand your scenario better.

Comment: write your whole code

Answer (score 0):

Add the timepicker.js in ur html and use below jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>  
<!-- core, slider, datepicker -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timepicker.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {  
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({  
      showSecond: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 2,
      stepMinute: 10,
      stepSecond: 10
      ...  
     });  
});  
</script>  

<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="">
```